# Security concerns about SQL Server on Azure Windows VM

Tags: sql-server, azure

We need to migrate our SQL Server DBs on Windows 2003 to new environments with Windows 2008 or above. 
The users access the current DB mainly via Excel from their desktop PC.

I have considered Azure as one of the alternatives, but as far as I've studied, it's difficult for us to adopt it as there are security concerns as below.

1. SQL Server authentication is the only alternative and anyone can access the DBs once they come to know the username and the password.
2. The communication of data can't be encrypted though the stored data can.

Could anyone point out if my understanding is wrong or advise me if you know any ways to untangle my concerns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server authentication is not your only option. If you create a site-to-site VPN tunnel between your organization's network and the virtual network in Azure, you can join the VMs into your AD domain. Here's an answer on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/518937/how-do-i-add-a-vm-hosted-on-windows-azure-to-my-local-active-directory/518939#518939) for how to do that.

By using site-to-site or point-to-site VPN your users are connecting through an encrypted tunnel so the data is encrypted in transit.

The other advantage of VPN is that you can setup your Network Security Group rules such that the SQL servers can only be accessed from within the virtual network or through the VPN.

Comment: juunas, thanks so much for your great advice! If we can adopt it, both of my concerns will be untangled. The link will help me a lot. I really appreciate it!